# Aligning text to the center of a div under an already centered logo

Tags: html, css

Rather than try to center text under an already centered logo in 1 div would I be better to create 2 divs and center the logo at the bottom of top div and text at top of bottom div? I have managed to center the logo in the center of the page but can only manage to center the text at the top of the screen.  I am wanting to place under the logo.

```css
.home-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.homepage {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.home-text {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
  <img src="assets/img/home-logo.png" class="home-logo">
  <p class="home-text"><a href="geelong.html">Geelong</a></p>
  <p class="home-text"><a href="ballarat.html">Ballarat</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.home-logo {
  align-self: center;
  width: 50px;
}

.homepage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.home-text {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150" class="home-logo">
  <p class="home-text" style="padding-top: 25px;"><a href="geelong.html">Geelong</a></p>
  <p class="home-text"><a href="ballarat.html">Ballarat</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: seems to work, the words are now centered over logo, but how to place them under the logo, if I add a margin top it will only apply to the bottom word

Comment: what do you mean "over logo". But yea you can definitly play with margins or padding.

Comment: well the logo was and is centered, and so now are words with your css but logo is covering words, if i add margin-top to the words only the bottom word will be affected and move down

Comment: well thats not true, try to run code sniped. Both text are correctly positioned under picture. If text is placed under logo in your code, there could be some other issue.

Comment: No problem, Happy coding. If you feel that my or other answers were useful, feel free to upvote.

Comment: I have modified my answer for your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and do no longer need absolute positioning.

```css
.home-logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.homepage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.home-text {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="home-logo">
  <p class="home-text"><a href="geelong.html">Geelong</a></p>
  <p class="home-text"><a href="ballarat.html">Ballarat</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: this works how I want the text Gerard but it puts the logo etc all at the top of the div again?

Comment: I have adjusted the code and set a height for .homepage

Answer (score 0):

```
.home-logo{
 height: 100px;}

.homepage{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;}

.home-text{
  font-size: 28px;
  color:#000;
  text-align: center;}

 <div class="homepage">
    <img src="assets/img/home-logo.png" class="home-logo">
    <p class="home-text"><a href="geelong.html">Geelong</a></p>
    <p class="home-text"><a href="ballarat.html">Ballarat</a></p>
 </div>
```